# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cx_Oracle' spyder

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I want to connect `Python 3.6` (Spyder) to `Oracle`.
When connecting I get the error as

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cx_Oracle'

Answer (score 2):

Just run the following command in Anaconda prompt `conda install cx_oracle`, should work now. 
I found it [here](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/vkwdX08I3Lc)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you already tried `pip3 install cx_Oracle`? If you're on a mac and have done this and still receiving ModuleNotFoundError then try `pip3 install --user cx_Oracle`. To confirm the module is installed run `pip3 freeze` to list all python3 modules currently installed.

Comment: pip3 freeze
  File "<ipython-input-9-49b233f1e021>", line 1
    pip3 freeze
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Where are you putting pip3 freeze? It's a command that should be run from the terminal.

Comment: Where are you putting pip3 freeze? It's a command that should be run from the terminal.

Comment: Try `pip freeze`

Comment: >>> pip freeze
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip freeze
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> pip3 freeze
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip3 freeze
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Looks like you're running python in the terminal, exit it and then run `pip3 freeze` without running python

Comment: Where to run this command? Please tell me exactly where should I run this command

Comment: I told you already, EXIT Python on the terminal then from your bash terminal run it. You CANNOT run it from Python...

Comment: The installation instructions for cx_Oracle are at http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html